# How to force user to allow location-services and push notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, gps, location

How can we force user to allow the permissions the app requires? I wanna force the user to allow both location-services and push-notifications, but at the moment, if user click "dont allow", the user can access all functionality.

I would like to loop the pop-up message where user must click allow. Meaning, if user click "dont allow", the popup will keep appear until user selects "allow".

Maybe there's a library with such functionality?

EDIT:

my code right now:

```
func checkIfUserEnabledLocation(){

        if !hasLocationPermission() {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location Permission Required", message: "Please enable location permissions in settings.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: {(cAlertAction) in
                //Redirect to Settings app
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION")!)
            })

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func hasLocationPermission() -> Bool {
        var hasPermission = false
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
                hasPermission = false
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                hasPermission = true
            default:
                print("hello")
            }
        } else {
            hasPermission = false
        }

        return hasPermission
    }
```

This code I fire from button-clicks etc in the app. But I want on startup, the user can't proceed to app at all if they don't allow locations!

Comment: First of all, forcing permissions is impossible and is against Apple's policies. What you could do instead is to create a landing page for users who denied the permissions. Another thing you could do is permission priming (look it up) so that there will be a smaller chance of users to deny a permission

Comment: Ok. Do you mean that there's no way of looping the popup preventing the user to use any functionality of the app until the "allow" is tapped?

Comment: You can "loop" - You just need to check the permission status each time your app returns to the foreground and prompt the user if the permission is still denied; But there is a chance Apple will reject your app if you don't allow some functionality without location  and notification access. Be aware that using `prefs-root` is considered private API and *will* lead to your app being rejected during review.  You can only open your own apps preferences.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok great, thanks! What do you mean with prefs-root and that it will lead to rejection? EDIT: Found it, thanks for the alert! Will change this.

Comment: @Paulw11 URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) this should be OK right?

Comment: Yes, that is OK.

Comment: @Paulw11 Perfect! Thank you very much for the input about this. Also, I wonder why would apple reject the app if the user needs to activate locations?

Comment: They may not; it depends if your app *really* can't function without user location; generally you are expected to follow the user's wishes and provide the functionality that you can without location. For example an app might not allow people to "check in" to a venue without providing their location but could still let users search for venues, see the details of those venues and who else has checked in there.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok got it! Thank you very much Sir.